# setup table level Autovacuuming on postgres database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6, autovacuum

I am trying to setup table level Autovacuuming on postgres database. What all metrices I need to collect and analyze specific to that particular table? 
I have to enable autovacuuming on all the tables wherever it is required.(With most inserts/deletes probably). How do I proceed on this? 
Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't the default vacuuming work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just leave all the default settings as they are. Autovacuum is enabled by default and will usually do the right thing. In my professional life I find that newbies who are trying to tune the autovacuum parameters usually do more harm than good.

One parameter I'd recommend changing is `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`, which I would lower to 2ms (which is the default setting from v12 on). That way, you run less risk of having a too lazy autovacuum.

If you ask a more specific question, you can get a more specific answer.

Comment: I dont think if I would be able to leave it as default, I have few tables with count 900m which cant wait dead tuples to reach 20% before autovacum trigger. Can you give me a query to identify the for which I need to setup autovacuum. (I believe the most accessed tables).
I want to have a setup where I can enable autovacuum on table level for huge/Most accessed tables and all others i can have global autovacuum enabled.
What are the things I should make a note of?

Comment: There is no fundamental problem with waiting for 20% dead tuples with a large table, but if you want to vacuum these tables more frequently (which may hurt), lower `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` for these tables.